# Google analytics event tracking not working (2016)

Tags: javascript, html, analytics, event-tracking

I've reviewed many posts on stackoverflow and cannot seem to find an answer to my problem. For some reason my event tracking is not being trigger from localhost, dev server or production server, is something wrong with the code I am using?

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
        (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

ga('create', 'UA-11111111-11', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I have tried Google Analytics being loading in the head and above the body tag.  Neither of which has worked. I am using "Google Tag Assistant" form chrome and the following HTML code, and nothing...

```
<a href="#" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'another-click', eventAction: 'click-home', eventLabel: 'click', eventValue: 1});">test</a>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Read how to send events to GA. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#using_the_ga_command_queue

Comment: I think 'Google Tag Assistant' doesn't detect event tracking. Use [Event Tracking Tracker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/event-tracking-tracker/npjkfahkbgoagkfpkidpjdemjjmmbcim?hl=en-US) to detect tracking. Also [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) takes some time to display tracking if any.

Comment: The event tracking code itself is fine. Are you checking in your standard reports? Data doesn't get processed right away, and you'll need to wait up to 24 hours for processing. In the meantime, check real-time or GA Debugger or dev console.

Comment: Thanks for the Event Tracking Tracker suggestion Rohit and the Google Analytics Debugger nyuen.  I am seeing results with both of those tools.  Looks like the tracking is working after all.

Comment: OK, then all you have to do is wait for the events to be processed, which could take up to 24 hours. Check again tomorrow.